# Highcharts dataLabels allowOverlap not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

In my `dataLabels` options for a series I have set `allowOverlap` to `false`.  However, I'm still getting overlapping labels.  My actual implementation is admittedly really custom and bespoke, and I've tried to create a simple jsfiddle to reproduce this, but can't.

However, I have tracked it down to what I think is the problem, at least in the html output.

In [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/rbg2dj45/), when I inspect the labels elements in Chrome Dev Tools, I see something like the following for the first few labels:

[image]

It seems that the class `highcharts-data-label-hidden` goes together with an `opacity: 0` and this acts to hide the label concerned.  Where that class label is not applied, `opacity` is set to `1`, to show the label.  It works as it should; there are no overlapping labels in this example.

However, with the output from my own code I see something like:

[image]

In my output, all labels are shown; none are hidden; and many are overlapping.  It seems that the `highcharts-data-label-hidden` class is being correctly applied to certain labels, i.e. those that should be hidden to avoid overlap.  But at the same time, the `opacity` of these elements is set to `1` rather than `0`... in fact *all* elements have an `opacity` of `1`... and hence *all* my labels are showing, and many are overlapping as a result.

Sure enough, if I dynamically edit the style tags in Dev Tools to change `opacity` to `0` for those elements having the `highcharts-data-label-hidden` class, the labels are nicely laid out without any overlap.

I have tried in vain for hours to work out why my code is setting `opacity` to `1` even for these labels that should be hidden, despite apparently assigning the `highcharts-data-label-hidden` class correctly.  I need your help, even based on this admittedly limited information.

One clue may be that I also notice that `highcharts-data-label-color-0` class appears in the working example for each element, whereas `highcharts-data-label-color-undefined` appears in mine.  Looking at the HC source code, this appears to come from `dataLabel.addClass(' highcharts-data-label-color-' + point.colorIndex ...`, so `point.colorIndex` in mine must be ending up as `undefined`, but I'm not sure why, or whether that is related to the problem I'm seeing with the non-hidden labels.  I am doing some 'advanced' stuff with point and label colouring in my code, so that I can set the colour of the label to match the colour of the point, even where a colour gradient is in effect (this is done after the chart loads).  But I don't do anything to the label opacity, so far as I know... wouldn't even know how... the `dataLabels` object doesn't even have an `opacity` element to change.

Any help appreciated!

**EDIT**

Finally managed to make a [simple repro](https://jsfiddle.net/wt0am7d5/), just to prove that I'm not going mad!  If you run this example, and inspect the overlapping label elements, you will see that (like described above) many have the `highcharts-data-label-hidden` class and yet also have `opacity: 1`, making them visible when they shouldn't be.

The (partial) solution appears to be to do a `series.update(false)` after each series loop (only one series in this example), rather than a `chart.update()` at the end... as per [this updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/7uh0y5ab/).  Question: why isn't it necessary to pass `true` into the update?

However, whilst this is an improvement, there is still an oddity... after loading, try hitting the Unset Extremes button... the labels overlap again.

And it's not just calling `setExtremes()` with no args that does this... load [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/aLnfuky2/) and hit Set Extremes once (OK) and then twice (NOT OK)... the only change in this example is to use wider extremes than in the original, so that labels overlap.  Even more weirdly in this example, some labels remain hidden, while others don't... it's not all or nothing.

Even with the first [simple repro](https://jsfiddle.net/wt0am7d5/), which doesn't work on opening, if you hit Set Extremes, then Unset Extremes, the labels no longer overlap.  But hit Unset Extremes again, and they overlap again.  Can't work out what is going on here.

In fact, having spent a while producing this repro, I now notice that the [original example](https://jsfiddle.net/rbg2dj45/) I gave at the very start of my post also shows this behaviour, without needing the `load()` event... open this again... looks fine at first but then hit the Unset Extremes button... labels overlap!  And in this [slight modification](https://jsfiddle.net/6kfwz1g4/) all I have done is widen the range for Set Extremes... load that and hit Set Extremes (OK) and then again (NOT OK).

How do I ensure non-overlapping labels in this context, at all times, regardless of what axis extremes are set (and in what order the extremes are set)?

Comment: Interesting case, it's a shame that you are not able to reproduce this behaviour on the online editor. May I ask which version of Highcharts do you use?

Comment: The latest: `8.1.2`.  I appreciate that it may be difficult to help in this case, but I thought that someone with more detailed knowledge and experience of the highcharts code than me might have some insights which might help figure out what is going on... it's driving me crazy!

Comment: Please test it in some previous versions like 7 or 8.0.0 - it might be some kind of regression after the last release. If this wouldn't help I don't think that more can be done in this case without code sample/reproduction.

Comment: Reverting to `7.0.1` gives an `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at Object.a.isObject`.  But interestingly, it forced me into zooming into the chart... no uncaught error on zooming... and labels show fine without overlap!  Then when I go back to `8.1.2` and try this, the same thing happens... no error but when I zoom (even keeping roughly the same chart range) the labels are hidden just fine... the  key difference being that `opacity: 0` now appears when `highcharts-data-label-hidden` is present (as suspected is the problem).  Weird.

Comment: Interesting case, but without the code, I can only guess what is happening.

Comment: Even with the code I can only guess ;-)

Comment: @SebastianWędzel I finally managed to reproduce this with a simple jsfiddle... see the EDIT in my original post... I did already find a *partial* solution but still there is something unresolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for reproducing the issue. Just like I thought before - it is a regression. Everything used to work fine in the 8.0.4 version. I already reported it on Highcharts GitHub issue channel where you can follow this thread:

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13742

The last stable version: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vwc34nhz/

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/8.0.4/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>

<button id="setextremes">Set extremes</button>
<button id="unsetextremes">Unset extremes</button>
```

If you don't need any new features please use the 8.0.4 version until our core developers will fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks... finally got there!